# Laravel ReflectionException error : Repository doesn't exist

Tags: laravel

I know this question lil bit old, but i still can't find the right solution. I've been search the internet for days, and try several solutions, check my files path, update the composer.json and and dump-autoload it,  but still no luck. I still get the following error :

```
ReflectionException
Class Cribbb\Storage\User\EUserRepository does not exist
```

here's my code.

The controller (app/controllers/UsersControllers.php) :

```
<?php

use Cribbb\Storage\User\IUserRepository as User; 

class UsersController extends \BaseController {

    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return Response
     */

    public function __construct(User $user)
    {
      $this->user = $user;
    }
?>
```

The interface (lib/Cribbb/Storage/User/IUserRepository.php) :

```
<?php

namespace Cribbb\Storage\User;

interface IUserRepository{

    public function all();
    public function find($id);  
    public function create($input);
}

?>
```

The Repository (lib/Cribbb/Storage/User/EUserRepository.php) :

```
<?php

namepsace Cribbb\Storage\User;

use User;

class EUserRepository implements IUserRepository
{

    public function all()
    {
        return User::all(); 
    }

    public function find($id)
    {
        return User::find($id);
    }

    public function create($input)
    {
        return User::create($input);
    }



} 

?>
```

The Service Provider (lib/Cribbb/Storage/StorageServiceProvider.php) :

```
<?php

namespace Cribbb\Storage;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class StorageServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {

  public function register()
  {
    $this->app->bind(
      'Cribbb\Storage\User\IUserRepository',
      'Cribbb\Storage\User\EUserRepository'
    );
  }

} ?>
```

i also included the service provider in app/config/app.php as follow :

```
'providers' => array(
...
'Cribbb\Storage\StorageServiceProvider'
);
```

and i added app/lib the composer.json :

```
"autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "app/commands",
            "app/controllers",
            "app/models",
            "app/database/migrations",
            "app/database/seeds",
            "app/tests/TestCase.php",
            "app/lib"
        ]
    }
```

The odd part about this is, while IUserRepository and EUserRepository is in the same folder, Laravel only detect the IUserRepository. It seems cannot find the EUserRepository.
Do I miss something important? any advice guys?

Comment: Have you double-checked filenames?

Comment: Yes. I have double-checked them. I even create a new file, name them with different name, put it in the same folder along with EUserRepository, bind it in service provider. and laravel still throwing the same error.

Comment: Hi Philip! Why don't you register the folder as PSR-0 or PSR-4?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
namepsace Cribbb\Storage\User;
```

should it be namespace?

**EDIT**

The Repository (lib/Cribbb/Storage/User/EUserRepository.php) has a typo:

```
<?php

namepsace Cribbb\Storage\User;
```

Because you didn't use autoloading it just loads as `\EUserRepository` class. (root scope)

Comment: No, it shouldn't. i put StorageServiceProvider.php in lib/Cribbb/Storage/ while my repositories and interface in lib/Cribbb/Storage/User. Anyway, i've tried your advice. change the namespace into Cribbb\Storage\User, laravel throw me "cannot find serviceprovider" error. then i moved the file to lib/Cribbb/Storage/User , updated 'providers' aaray in app/config/app.php, dump-autoload, but still no luck. :(

Comment: you get a typo there in lib/Cribbb/Storage/User/EUserRepository.php

Comment: (@veelasky can you edit the answer to be a little more specific to answering the problem (maybe mention the file, the fact that it's a typo) and I'll happily +1.)

Comment: @veelasky oh, you're right. a typo, my bad. it works... thanks :D

Comment: @alexrussel me too. who the hell gave him -1? i accepted the answer. :)