# How to setup "Loosely Coupled" design pattern in "Laravel"

Tags: php, laravel-5, loose-coupling

I am very new to “Laravel” world so I could be wrong in very basics.

I am trying to setup a project with “Loosely Coupled” design pattern. I have looked into following tutorials:

http://vegibit.com/laravel-repository-pattern/

http://heera.it/laravel-repository-pattern#.Vtaepfl97IU

and also looked into following threads of SO:

[Laravel 5 - Interface is not instantiable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29690056/laravel-5-interface-is-not-instantiable)

[Laravel ReflectionException error : Repository doesn't exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23056080/laravel-reflectionexception-error-repository-doesnt-exist)

but couldn’t got the results.

So here is my application structure:

```
    -app

       -Providers
                 IOCProvider
       -Repositories
           -Abstracts
                     IUserRepository
           -Concrete
                     UserRepository
```

Here is "IUserRepository":

```
  <?php
   namespace App\Repositories\Abstracts;

     interface IUserRepository {
           public function getUserByID($ID);

        }
```

And UserRepository:

```
    <?php
      namespace App\Repositories\Concrete;
      use App\Repositories\Abstracts;
      use app\Model;
      class UserRepository implements IUserRepository {
         public function getUserByID($id){
           $user=  User::find(1);
           return $user;
         }
     }
```

IOCProvider.php:

```
    <?php
     namespace App\Providers;
     use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

      class IocProvider extends ServiceProvider {
           public function register()
           {

             $this->app->bind('App\Repositories\Abstracts\IUserRepository', 'App\Repositories\Concrete\UserRepository');

          }
      }
```

And composer.json:

```
   "autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/",
        "App\\Repositories\\Abstracts":"app/Repositories/Abstract",
        "App\\Repositories\\Concrete":"app/Repositories/Concrete"
    }
},
```

Now I am getting this error:

```
   ReflectionException in Container.php line 798:
     Class App\Repositories\Abstracts\IUserRepository does not exist
```

Please guide me what am I doing wrong.

Your help would really be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: I think loose coupling is not a design pattern. It's a principle/recommendation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your UserRepository try changing this : `use App\Repositories\Abstracts`
to this : `use App\Repositories\Abstracts\IUserRepository`

On a side note, as you are new to Laravel - go to Laracasts.com. There is no better laravel resource for tutorials then that site. It is the defacto recommendation for all new laravel people. *(For example hre is a good set of free beginning laravel video tutorials: https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-from-scratch)*

Good luck

Comment: Thanx for your response, I have tried what you suggested but still the same result.

Comment: Wait...I missed something back a step. DId you register the service provider in your app in the config\app.php file?

Comment: Yes I have registered that with this line:
App\Providers\IocProvider::class,

Comment: After adding the PSR-4 lines to composer.json did you update the autoloader with composer update or composer dump-autoload?

Comment: There is a typo in your composer.json. You have Abstract instead of Abstracts <-- missing s. Make sure you update the composer autoload after fixing it.

Comment: Oh Thanx for mention. . I have corrected the spelling. . .and I didn't update the autoloader. . How to update it? from command-line?

Comment: Yes, from command line you want to run `composer update` or `composer dump-autoload` from inside your root folder where your app is stored. (Update - https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#update)  (Dump-Autoload - https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#dump-autoload)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105151/discussion-between-user2517610-and-icehawg).